# How to get extended json response from ASP.net controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am working on ASP.net MVC Applciation

I am facing difficulty in preparing json response to return from a controller action method.

I need some thing like this:

```
{
    "cityMap": {"11": "Chennai", "12": "Mumbai", "13": "Delhi"},
    "rows": [
        { "SID": "1",  "SNAME": "ABC", "CITY": "11" },
        { "SID": "2",  "SNAME": "XYZ", "CITY": "12" },
        { "SID": "3",  "SNAME": "ACX", "CITY": "13" },
        { "SID": "4",  "SNAME": "KHG", "CITY": "13" },
        { "SID": "5",  "SNAME": "ADF", "CITY": "12" },
        { "SID": "6",  "SNAME": "KKR", "CITY": "11" }
    ]
}
```

I have cityMap values in the `sortedlist` names slLocations

I have row values in the form of list liStudents

I am using the following syntax to send the json response:

```
return JSON(new { rows=liStudents},jsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)
```

By using the above syntax , i am getting the json response like this:

```
 {
  "rows": [
            { "SID": "1",  "SNAME": "ABC", "CITY": "11" },
            { "SID": "2",  "SNAME": "XYZ", "CITY": "12" },
            { "SID": "3",  "SNAME": "ACX", "CITY": "13" },
            { "SID": "4",  "SNAME": "KHG", "CITY": "13" },
            { "SID": "5",  "SNAME": "ADF", "CITY": "12" },
            { "SID": "6",  "SNAME": "KKR", "CITY": "11" }
        ]
  }
```

Please help on how to extend json response to above by using liStudents and liLocations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the desired `cityMap` property to the anonymous object that you are passing to the view:

```
var model = new
{
    cityMap = slLocations,
    rows = liStudents,
}
return JSON(model, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

This obviously assumes that the `slLocations` variable is a `SortedList<string, string>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darin ..It worked beautifully..i am struggling on this from an hour..saved my time..